# Convert table in R into a single row

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose, reshape2

I want to convert a data frame with n rows and n columns into a single row with column names and row names appended

For example i want the following table to be converted into a single row

```
   Country         Percentage
   United States    97.89%
   United Kingdom   0.65%
   Switzerland      0.50%
   Ireland          0.48%
   Singapore        0.45%
   Hong Kong        0.03%
```

Like this

```
Country_United States_Percentage    Country_United Kingdom_Percentage
97.89%                                       0.65%
```

And so on

Comment: `dplyr::spread()` ? might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you pretty close:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Percentage, 
  "United States", 97.89,
  "United Kingdom", 0.65,
  "Switzerland", 0.5,
  "Ireland", 0.48,
  "Singapore", 0.45,
  "Hong Kong", 0.03
)

spread(df, Country, Percentage, sep='_')
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful